# Proving $E[h(X_n)]\rightarrow E[h(X)]$ given some conditions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I lost points for trying to prove the following theorem
[image: Convergence in mean]

but I can't seem to locate where my proof (given below) fails.

Proof: For each $\epsilon>0$, we can find a natural number $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $|h(x)|<\epsilon g(x)$ outside of $[-N_{\epsilon},N_{\epsilon}]$. Also since $h(x)$ is continuous:

1. $|h(x)|$ has an upper bound inside $[-N_{\epsilon},N_{\epsilon}]$, which we will call $U$.
2. we have $h(X_n)\rightarrow^{a.s.} h(X)$.

Then, for all $n$, we have:
$$E\bigg[|h(X_n)|\bigg]=E\bigg[|h(X_n)|\mathbb{1}_{\big[|X_n|>N_{\epsilon}\big]}\bigg]+E\bigg[|h(X_n)|\mathbb{1}_{\big[|X_n|\leq N_{\epsilon}\big]}\bigg]$$
$$\leq \epsilon E\bigg[ g(X_n)\bigg] + \mathbb{P}(|X_n|\leq N_\epsilon)U \leq \epsilon K + U < \infty $$.

Then because of 2. and the dominated convergence theorem, the proof is completed.

Any advice or remark is welcomed, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have proved that $\sup_n \mathbb{E}[|h(X_n)|] < \infty$. This is not the required hypothesis for the dominated convergence theorem. For the dominated convergence theorem you would need to find a function $f$ such that $\sup_n |h(X_n)| \leq f$ and $\mathbb{E}[f] < \infty$.

Comment: Apparently there is a generalized DCT which makes this proof valid, but it isn't the one we covered in class. You are correct, thank you
(Gen. DCT) http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem

Answer (score 1):

Note that you want to prove that $E(h(X)n)-h(X))\to 0.$ As pointed out in the previous answer, you have merely shown that $\sup_{n}E(|h(X_n)|)<\infty.$ So let us re-write what you have written with slight modifications. Observe that $$E(h(X_n))=E\left(h(X_n)1_{(|X_n|\le N_{\epsilon})}\right)+E\left(h(X_n)1_{(|X_n|> N_{\epsilon})}\right).$$

Now DCT (or in fact BCT) is applicable to the random variables $h(X_n)1_{(|X_n|\le N_{\epsilon})}.$ Argue that $h(X_n)1_{(|X_n|\le N_{\epsilon})}\to h(X)1_{|X|\le N_{\epsilon}}$ and therefore $E\left(h(X_n)1_{(|X_n|\le N_{\epsilon})}\right)\to E(h(X)1_{(|X|\le N_{\epsilon})}).$

Now show that  as $\epsilon\to 0,$ we have $E\left(h(X_n)1_{|X_n|>N_{\epsilon}}\right)\to 0$ and $E(h(X)1_{|X|\ge N_{\epsilon}})\to 0.$ This is immediate because by your choice of $\epsilon$, you have that $$E(|h(Y)|1_{|Y|>N_{\epsilon}})\le \epsilon E(g(Y))$$ for any $Y.$ This is where you use the hypothesis that $E(g(X_n))\le K$ for all $K$ (and a concsequence of this is that $E(g(X))\le K$ by Fatou's lemma).